# Failed to resolve: org.jitsi.react:jitsi-meet-sdk:+

Tags: android, jitsi-meet

I am trying to integrate Jitsi Meet Android SDK into a simple project in native Android but it is failing to build and throwing the following error:

```
Failed to resolve: org.jitsi.react:jitsi-meet-sdk:+
```

I followed the [jitsi-meet documentation](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/tree/master/android#use-pre-build-sdk-artifactsbinaries) for setting up pre-build SDK which only had two simple instructions :

1. To add the maven dependency in Project gradle:

   buildscript {

   ```
       repositories {
           google()
           jcenter()
           maven {
               url "https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-maven-repository/raw/master/releases"
           }
       }
       dependencies {
           classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'


           // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
           // in the individual module build.gradle files
       }
   }
   ```
2. Add the gradle dependency in Module gradle:

   `implementation('org.jitsi.react:jitsi-meet-sdk:+') { transitive = true }`

I did not find any other post related to this same issue, so my guess is there is something that I am missing. Can someone please help me out here? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had added the maven dependency in the wrong place. It goes in the project gradle, under `allprojects->repositories`.

Answer (score 0):

implementation ('org.jitsi.react:jitsi-meet-sdk:3.+') { transitive = true }

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score -3):

This problem gets Windows-only devices

You can try to use a non-Windows operating system to work

[More information from the source](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/issues/3392#issuecomment-415017712)

Comment: Please don't share misguiding information, and when find out that your opinion was wrong, please delete or correct it, to keep the community clear, Thanks :)