# Failed to resolve: org.jitsi.react:jitsi-meet-sdk:3.+

Tags: android, android-studio, jitsi

I tried changing the compilesdk and mindsdk versions as told [here](https://exerror.com/solved-execution-failed-for-task-appcheckdebugaarmetadata/). I read all the other posts regarding the same but none worked so far. I have looked at the previous answers [ans1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51998175/failed-to-resolve-org-jitsi-reactjitsi-meet-sdk) and [ans2](https://community.jitsi.org/t/error-failed-to-resolve-org-jitsi-react/22427) . They didn't helped.

When I try to run the project it throws multplie errors. I think the main problem is because of this one

> Could not find any matches for org.jitsi.react:jitsi-meet-sdk:3.+ as no versions of org.jitsi.react:jitsi-meet-sdk are available.

[image: error1]

**build.gradle(My application)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-maven-repository/raw/master/releases"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.gradle(app)**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdk 30

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-common-ktx:20.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.3')
    implementation ('org.jitsi.react:jitsi-meet-sdk:3.+') { transitive = true }

}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is there any problem with the question I posted? I can elaborate more if needed. Please let me know what I should add. I am stuck on this since yesterday.

Comment: in my case my ip blocked raw.github

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find a workaround for this. You've to paste the maven URL into settings.gradle file. Some other user was facing a problem similar to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70139843/why-is-no-allprojects-in-my-build-gradle-android-studio) . I did the same and it's working fine.

[image: settings.gradle]

Answer (score 1):

+1  / Failed to resolve: org.jitsi.react:jitsi-meet-sdk:3.+

5 min
I had added the maven dependency in the wrong place. It goes in the project gradle, under allprojects->repositories.

- new fail
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'My Application'.

> Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'maven' was added by build file 'build.gradle'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was with the SDK version

I replaced this line

```
implementation ('org.jitsi.react:jitsi-meet-sdk:+') { transitive = true }
```

with this line

```
implementation ('org.jitsi.react:jitsi-meet-sdk:5.1.0') { transitive = true }
```

Answer (score 1):

To download you have to set dns (google) in your pc and check with below link:

https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using#windows

Comment: Please take a little more care with your phrasings, vocabulary, punctuation, redundancy of phrasing, use of blanks, capitalisation.. Perfect English is not required on StackOverflow, but some care which does not require high skills is.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using React-Native < 0.60, you should use a version < 2.0.0.
For versions higher than 2.0.0, you need to add the following piece of code in your metro.config.js file to avoid conflicts between react-native-jitsi-meet and react-native in metro bundler.

> const blacklist = require('metro-config/src/defaults/blacklist');
> module.exports = {
> resolver: {
> blacklistRE: blacklist([
> /ios/Pods/JitsiMeetSDK/Frameworks/JitsiMeet.framework/assets/node_modules/react-native/.*/,
> ]),
> },
> };

ref: https://github.com/skrafft/react-native-jitsi-meet

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, the issue is because Android Studio is not able to download the repository. You might see errors such as Connection Timout or Service Unavailable or even forbidden. Here are the steps to debug it :

1. As per [Jitsi Documentation](https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/dev-guide/dev-guide-android-sdk/), You need to have

   maven {
   url "https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-maven-repository/raw/master/releases"
   }

As mentioned by [darkexodus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10792358/darkexodus) in [This answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70743997/7710739)

2. After you sync your project and run it, if you have build issues, check the build logs in detail (click the left side top level error and see the full build logs)
3. If you find a line that says Connection Timeout, then you should also find a url in the error, copy the url and paste it in your browser. (In my case it was this url https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jitsi/jitsi-maven-repository/master/releases/org/jitsi/react/jitsi-meet-sdk/8.1.2/jitsi-meet-sdk-8.1.2.pom )
4. If the browser is not loading the url, then, the issue is with your network.
5. If you paste the url into [IsItDownORJustMe](https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/) website, you will come to know the status of the website.
6. If the link is active, then, confirmed, problem is in your network.
7. If you are in an office setup, you need to contact your IT Admin and share the url which is not accessible, they will unblock it in firewall.
8. If it is your home setup, check out how to set DNS Server in your operating system / modem. I was using ubuntu, and it was just a matter of settings change.

Here is the DNS Preferred : [Fixing Network Issue](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/42655#discussioncomment-4641544)

Then try sync and run your project, worked for me.